# wordpress mixed content with https

Tags: wordpress, http, https, mixed-content

I'm having a problem migrating my current http wordpress site to https. I'm getting a lot of mixed content "was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script" (js and css) . I already set the wp-config.php to home and site url to https but still no luck. Anyone knows what is the parent protocol this was being link?

Thanks

Comment: Could you put how did you solved your problem for any other person who need a solution ?

Comment: There is a wordpress plugin called Insecure content fixer which I installed